# Django add multiple Users to lobby model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to add Users to my players field in the lobby but i dont know how.
Every user should be in just one lobby.

User Model

```
class GeoUser(AbstractUser):
        user_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

Lobby Model

```
class Lobby(models.Model):
    lobby_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=18, unique=True)
    
    players = # here i want to add multiple users that should be in the lobby
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to add `ForeignKey` in `GeoUser` model pointing to `Lobby` model. This is `OneToMany` relation for `Lobby`, because one `GeoUser` will be in one `Lobby`, but there is actually no limit on how many `GeoUser` objects can be in `Lobby`.

```
class GeoUser(AbstractUser):
    user_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    lobby = models.ForeignKey('Lobby', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None, related_name='users')

class Lobby(models.Model):
    lobby_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=18, unique=True)
    
    def players(self):
        return self.users.all()
```

To get all players just call:

```
lobby = Lobby.objects.first()
lobby.players()    # returns a QuerySet of all related GeoUser objects
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect Solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), which you would implement by:

```
players = models.ManyToManyField(GeoUser)
```

You do have the constraint that a user should be part of a maximum of 1 lobby. I guess you could technically iterate over all of the lobbies every time and check if the user is currently in any lobby. If you plan to have a lot of lobbies, then it would probably make sense to save the user's lobby in the User model.

In my opinion, it's much better to create separate model responsible for maintaining the relation between the user and the lobby (see Django documentation for the [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) parameter). Now you would be able to enforce uniqueness using [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/) and also save other metadata such as the timestamp of when they joined.

Comment: Thank you, but for now i am going with a Foreignkey in user model